# Issue while connecting to Hive using Pyhive Library

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, hive, port, pyhive

**I have installed all the required libraries (thrift, thrift-sasl, PyHive, sasl) and tried to make connection with hive using PyHive. Also using Python3
Expecting to have a successful connection to hive using PyHive library. I am doing this entire work on Azure virtual machine**

**I have tried with port 10000 and I am getting this error**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyhive_****.py", line 6, in 
conn = connect(host='localhost', port=10000, user='hive', auth_mechanism='NOSASL')

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/impala/dbapi.py", line 194, in connect
service = hs2.connect(host=host, port=port,

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 865, in connect
transport.open()

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 155, in open
return self.__trans.open()

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 146, in open
raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.NOT_OPEN, message=msg)

thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to any of [('127.0.0.1', 10000)

**I have changed the port to a working port and then it is throwing this error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyhive***.py", line 8, in 
cursor = conn.cursor()

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 129, in cursor
session = self.service.open_session(user, configuration)

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1190, in open_session
resp = self._rpc('OpenSession', req, True)

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1083, in _rpc
response = self._execute(func_name, request, retry_on_http_error)

File "/home/azureuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1144, in _execute
raise HiveServer2Error('Failed after retrying {0} times'
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Failed after retrying 3 times

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)